# SQL how to remove the last character of a string if it is not numeric?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-synapse

```
PhoneNumber
1111111
1111111name
1111111ext2222name
1111111ex222name
```

I have a column of phone numbers that looks like this. The phone number could be followed by an extension then followed by a name. I'd like to remove the name from the phone number. How can I make it?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just a bit of string manipulation

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([PhoneNumber] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('1111111')
,('1111111name')
,('1111111ext2222name')
,('1111111ex222name')
 
Select * 
      ,NewValue = substring([PhoneNumber],1,len([PhoneNumber])-patindex('%[0-9]%',reverse([PhoneNumber])))
 From  @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
PhoneNumber         NewValue
1111111             111111
1111111name         111111
1111111ext2222name  1111111ext222
1111111ex222name    1111111ex22
```